# container background repeat-y not working

Tags: html, css

Have the following html code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="container2">
            ...
    </div>
</div>
```

and the following css:

```
#container {
background: #323232 url(../images/container-bg.png) repeat-y;
position: relative;
min-height: 75%;
}

#container2 {
background: url(../images/container-bg-right.png) repeat-y right top;
}
```

but the image in #container2 is not repeating itself vertically after I added 'min-height: 75%' to #container.

Any advise is appreciated!

Comment: the url http://rackelastic.com/dev/new/draft2/ returns `403 Forbidden`

Comment: Sorry about that, it should be working now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out, here is what I did:

```
#container {
    background: #323232 url(../images/container-bg.png) repeat-y;
    position: relative;
    height: 75%;
}

#container2 {
    background: url(../images/container-bg-right.png) repeat-y right top;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your container2 background is not repeating because it has no height. So if you want it to repeat as much as container one just give it the same min-height as container1.

Comment: Thanks, I just did that; add 'min-height: 75%' to container2 but still the same.

Comment: I don't believe giving an element a height or min-height is required in order to repeat it vertically, as it isn't required to repeat it horizontally. I'm also having this problem, I can never get images to repeat-y!